# Laravel Vapor's AWS Runtime?

Tags: php, laravel, aws-lambda

It's my understanding that [Laravel Vapor](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/introduction.html#introduction) is built on top of [Bref](https://bref.sh/).  It's also my understanding that Bref works by providing users with [a custom AWS Runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html) for executing Lambda functions via PHP.

What's not clear to me is *which* [Bref runtime or runtimes](https://bref.sh/docs/runtimes/) Laravel Vapor uses.  Bref appears to support both PHP-FPM based runtimes, as well as a function/event driven runtime.

Does Vapor use the PHP-FPM runtime, the function/event driven runtime, or both?  Bonus question: are the sources that build the AWS layers for these runtimes available online anywhere?

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure (make that 100% sure) that Laravel Vapor is NOT built on top of Bref ... I think Vapor existed long before Bref saw the light of day.

I suppose that Vapor does include something similar-ish to Bref's PHP-FPM runtime, but I'm just guessing there.